# GIT - fatal: cannot use .idea/ as an exclude file

Tags: git

I worked on a project and after running git add I noticed a directory which was not intended to be in there. The directory to be removed is .idea/. After running

```
git config core.excludesfile .idea/
```

I got a message

```
fatal: cannot use .idea/ as an exclude file
```

And now my console has frozen, any git related command except dit diff throws the same error. How could I get my rep functioning normally? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add your directory to the file *named by* `core.excludesfile`, which normally defaults to `.gitignore`. The reason `git` freezes is that the ignore file gets checked by almost every command, but you have a folder instead of a file specified.

To fix your immediate problem, open `.git/config` in a text editor. You should see a section that has the following:

```
[core]
    ...
    excludesfile = .idea/
```

(`...` represents a bunch of other lines that you don't care about). Remove the line with `excludesfile`. That will restore your repo to using `.gitignore` as the list of excluded files.

To properly ignore your `.idea/` directory, open a file called `.gitignore` in your root project directory (make a new one if you have to). Add the following line to it:

```
.idea/
```

This will tell `git` to ignore any folders named `.idea` anywhere in your project. If you only want to ignore it in the root directory, add the following instead:

```
/.idea/
```

Since it appears from the question that you already added the file, you will have to remove it from the index as well as from your repo. Make sure to run the following:

```
git rm --cached .idea
```

Thanks to [@TimBiegeleisen's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50004845/git-fatal-cannot-use-idea-as-an-exclude-file/50004959#comment87026376_50004959) for the last part.

Comment: Good detective work, but I would also add that if the OP has already done `git add` to this file, then `git rm --cached` may be necessary as well. +1 otherwise.

Comment: Thank you, I solved it with your help, how everything works.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen. Good catch. I included your suggestion.

Comment: @Mad Physicist I upvoted, however, not sure I understand what do you mean by "selecting the answer"?

Comment: @Mad Physicist Thanks for suggestion, was not aware of that. Done.

Answer (score 4):

following **solution** helped me

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore
```