# fatal: cannot use node_modules as an excludesfile

Tags: linux, ubuntu, node-modules, gitignore

[fatal: cannot use node_modules as an excludesfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kxRF.png)
You can see here I am written alright in .gitignore files but its giving me error **fatal: cannot use node_modules as an excludesfiles**

Comment: Post text not images

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GIT - fatal: cannot use .idea/ as an exclude file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50004845/git-fatal-cannot-use-idea-as-an-exclude-file)

Answer (score -2):

This error comes when you using linux os. check your parent directories and remove other .gitignore files if any.

Otherwise this error will surely occurs if in (Home directory)parent of our project where .gitconfig file show you can see image if there written
excludefiles = node_modules simply change it to exclude = node_modules/ or delete that line.[solved error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkE4v.png)